# Cartan subalgebras of reductive subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, reductive-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}_1\subseteq\mathfrak{g}_2$ be an inclusion of reductive Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it always possible to find Cartan subalgebras $\mathfrak{h}_1\subseteq \mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{h}_2\subseteq \mathfrak{g}_2$ such that $\mathfrak{h}_1\subseteq \mathfrak{h}_2$?

Comment: Did you try it for semisimple Lie algebras (which are reductive)? What did you try anyway?

Comment: Let $\mathfrak g_2$ be semisimple. Take a nonzero nilpotent element in this and consider the one-dimensional, abelian subalgebra it generates.